# Ghost 1.0 Disqus Comment Count Not Reflecting the Post Comments

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, disqus, ghost

I recently updated my **Ghost** version from **0.11.11** to **1.12.0**

I also added a PAGE_IDENTIFIER as per the [Disqus - JavaScript configuration variables](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472098-javascript-configuration-variables)

The comment count on the index page is not reflecting the post comments.

This [link](http://jitblog.net/) displays the main page comment counts for each post, in particular the post for Firefox is **0 comments**

This [link](http://jitblog.net/firefox-does-not-display-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/) displays the Firefox post with Disqus comment count of 4.

**The following is my current script for comments**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
  (function () {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.async = true;
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = '//' + disqus.shortname + '.disqus.com/count.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0]).appendChild(s);
  }());
</script>
```

**I am using the following to create the comment count link**

```
<i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> <a href="{{url absolute="true"}}#disqus_thread" data-disqus-identifier="{{comment_id}}">Comments</a>
```

**The post comment script is as follows**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var disqus_config = function () {
    this.page.url = '{{url absolute="true"}}';
    this.page.identifier = '{{comment_id}}';
    this.page.title = '{{title}}';
  };

  /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
  (function () {
    var dsq = document.createElement('script');
    dsq.type = 'text/javascript';
    dsq.async = true;
    dsq.src = '//' + disqus.shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
  })();
</script>
```

**Questions**

I have recently updated the URL links using the mapper but will this pickup the new `page.identifier`?

If not, what steps can I take to fix the comment count?

**Investigation**

**1.** The `count.js` file is indeed loaded as the link text is being replaced after load.

**2.** I found that an object is created when the Disqus count script is loaded called DISQUSWIDGETS. The DISQUSWIDGETS.forum field is undefined.

**3.** jnowland on GitHub Gist has deconstructed the [count.js](https://gist.github.com/jnowland/6759321) file and it seems the DISQUSWIDGETS.forum has to be defined in order to set the correct details to retrieve the count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per jnowland's [count.js](https://gist.github.com/jnowland/6759321) file on GitHub Gist, the `disqus_shortname` must be declared and defined before executing the Disqus comment count script.

This will set the DISQUSWIDGETS.forum field correctly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var disqus_shortname = "MY_SHORTNAME"; // Replace MY_SHORTNAME with your DISQUS shortname.

  /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
  (function () {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.async = true;
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/count.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0]).appendChild(s);
  }());
</script>
```